# My docker container can ping a machine outside of its host but not the other way around

Tags: dockerfile, ping, docker-container, iproute

**Local Network = 192.168.100.0/24**

**Private Docker network = 172.18.0.0/16**

**Machine 1 = 192.168.100.5**

**Machine 2 = 192.168.100.7 , 172.18.0.1**

**Docker Container = 172.18.0.2**

On Machine 1, I did

`ip route add 172.18.0.0/16 via 192.168.100.7`

On Machine 2, I already allowed port forwarding by uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl.conf

I even did ip masquerading,

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

But for some reason i cant ping the docker container from Machine 1 but i can ping Machine 1 from the docker container and i don't know why

**If it helps, when creating the docker container, i used `-p 2222:22` as i wanted to connect via ssh**